# PHP $db PDO connection error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanted to make posts and comments system.
Posts worked fine, but comments had

> PHP error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:133 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(133): PDO->__construct('localhost', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 133. `

```
$db = new PDO ("localhost", "root", "");
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments");
$query->execute();
while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $message = $fetch['comment'];
    echo "<li class='com'><b>".ucwords($name)."</b> - ".$message."</li>";
}
```

It's element of table. Please help.

Comment: For now, you haven't selected a database. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Yes, but even If I had still same error

Comment: Please edit the code to its final version, with the selected db and all

Comment: How do people expect to get correct responses when the code they post is not complete?

Comment: Tip (for both OP and commenters): if you have an error in a given line of code, the error cannot be caused by the lines of code that execute afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a DSN when instantiating, replace `testdb` with the name of your database.

Change `localhost` to something like this `mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1`.

```
$db = new PDO ("mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost", "root", "");
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments");
$query->execute();
while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $name = $fetch['name'];
    $message = $fetch['comment'];
    echo "<li class='com'><b>".ucwords($name)."</b> - ".$message."</li>";
}
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

> **Usage**: public PDO::__construct ( string $dsn [, string $username [, string $password [, array $options ]]] )

Comment: Be sure to use the checkbox to accept the answer since it resolves your question, thank you

Comment: It tells me that I can't give +1 because I haven't got 15 reputation.

Comment: You can click the checkbox and out will accept the answer. The checkbox is below the down vote arrow,